# PostgREST normalised output instead of nested results

Tags: database, postgresql, postgrest

I'm trying to use PostgREST to query my database, my app is developed with React+Redux and I would like to get a normalised output from PostgREST.

Which means having this:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
      comments: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      author: 1
    },
    ...
  ],

  author: {
    1: {
      first_name: ...,
      last_name: ...,
      ...
    }
  },

  comments: {
    1: {
      ...
    },
    2: {
      ...
    },
    3: {
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
      comments: [{
        id: 1,
        ...
      },{
        id: 2,
        ...
      },{
        id: 3,
        ...
      },{
        id: 4,
        ...
      },{
        id: 5,
        ...
      }],
      author: {
        id: 1,
        first_name: ...,
        last_name: ...,
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I didn't find anything about it in the doc and would like to know if there's any easy way to achieve this.

Comment: PostgREST isn't designed to output things that way, but I think there's a workaround using a stored procedure to construct the response. Post an issue on the project's github repo and we can discuss it there.